# Not getting an output from my inputs

Tags: android

http://pastebin.com/YmeB2D1N

Essentially, my program has two EditTexts, a Button, and a TextView. You input a number/string into the EditText, and an output is supposed to be shown in the TextView.  However, all i get is a 'There is no Department'.  How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere that you are setting the values of department or name variables.
you can do:

```
EditText departmentEt = (EditText)findViewById(r.id.department_edit_text));
EditText nameEt = (EditText)findViewById(r.id.name_edit_text));
search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener) {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(deparmentEt.length() > 0) {
            department = Integer.parseInt(departmentEt.getText().toString());
        }
        if(nameEt.length() > 0) {
            name = nameEt.getText().toString();
        }

        //The rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: IT looks good, but i've still got a set of errors to deal with.   if(department.length() > 0) {
                        department = Integer.parseInt(department.getText().toString());
                    }
                    if(name.length() > 0) {
                        name = name.getText().toString();                                                                                                                       At department.length/getText =  Cannot invoke length/getText() on the primitive type int.  And at name.getText, The method getText() is undefined for the type String.

Answer (score 1):

use **onTextChangedListener** for **EditText** and

in that method write get value of **EditText** and set it to **TextView**.

I hope it works.

Code

```
textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        textView.setText(textMessage.getText().toString());
    }
});
```